# 'No such file' using Tamir.SharpSSH to download file via sftp

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, sftp

I'm getting error on `sftp.GetFileList(ftpHost)` with message *"No such file"*.

Using the given IP and credentials I've tested they have permissions to all the directories I'm connecting to.

```
string FileName = Label6.Text;
string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~");
string FolderName = "\\DL" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath + FolderName);
string rootPath1 = rootPath + FolderName;
string ftphost = "***.***.***.***";
string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + FileName;
int port = 22;

Sftp sftp = new Sftp("***.***.***.***", "@!#^@!^$", "!@#^#@#^&");
sftp.Connect(port);
sftp.GetFileList(ftphost);
ArrayList res = sftp.GetFileList(ftphost);
foreach (var item in res)
{
    if (item.ToString() != "." && item.ToString() != "..")
    Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    
}
sftp.Get(ftpfullpath, rootPath1);
```

Also the account used to connect to the FTP has a script on it that puts it into a specific directory, is it necessary to somehow redirect the `Get` or `GetFileList` to the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `GetFileList` method accepts a path to retrieve a listing for. Not hostname. You have specified the hostname in `Sftp` constructor already.
- The same for `Get` method.
- *Moreover, you are using SFTP protocol, why the `ftp://` prefix?*
- Note that you call `GetFileList` twice.
- SharpSSH is a poor choice. It's not maintained for years.